# Flex: navigateToURL() takes about 3-5+ seconds?

Tags: apache-flex, navigatetourl

My flex app has a call in it to:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(_rURL),'_self');
```

But it takes about 3-5 or even more seconds before it will leave the current page.

If I omit the '_self' the new window opens immediately and the page loads immediate...but only when I set it to _self I get a few seconds of a delay before it loads...I have no idea why but it is annoying.. I am wondering if anyone might have any idea why this is happening or anything I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior on my machine (XP, Flash 10), but you're right -- it seems like I've noticed this before on other projects.  Good question -- curious to see whether a answer bubbles up.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why use '_self'? Isn't that the default behavior if you omit it?

Comment: No, _blank is for this, but _self SHOULD be.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers process the request before redirecting to the new page. For example, if the URL is a file to be downloaded it will not redirect. You can use the name or ID of the window or frame to get the same effect, "top", "window", "parent", "self" (not _self) etc. More info here, http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserinspecific